# Docker build of strapi image not completing, stuck at localhost address

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, strapi

I am trying to create the docker image of my strapi project with cloud hosted mongodb atlas database. Below is my dockerfile code

```
FROM strapi/base

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

RUN npm run start:develop

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

I am running the below code to build the docker file

```
docker build .
```

I am not receiving any error but the problem is building of image is not completing, it sticks at  http://localhost:1337. How can I resolve this? I have attached the screenshot . TIA :)

[image: Docker build result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RUN npm run start:develop` step is never ending since it is running the server.

You can either write that step in your `CMD` and remove your existing `CMD ["npm","start"]`, or you can simply remove that step. It depends on your case.

Try the following Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM strapi/base

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

or

```sh
FROM strapi/base

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm"," run", "start:develop]
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. then when should I run RUN npm run start:develop

Comment: I believe `npm run start:develop` and `npm start` both start your server. So you should choose which one you need. Ideally, `npm start` is used in production scenarios where as `npm run start:develop` would be for local development.

Comment: Anything you `RUN` happens as part of building the image.  You don't need to start the server then.

Comment: @DavidMaze so I dont need to write npm run start:develop inside dockerfile?

Comment: @FaisalShani It depends on which one you need to keep. Because `npm start` and `npm run start:develop` are defined by you. So, you can choose which one you need inside the Dockerfile. It is just that you can not have both.

Comment: But whichever one you pick, it should be the image's `CMD` when a container is eventually run.  You do not need to `RUN` either as part of the build.